# Selecting from student and teacher table

Tags: mysql, sql

Old statement, for logging in I then check if the `results[0]` = the password which works.

```
'SELECT * FROM student WHERE username = ?',[username]
```

I now also have a `teacher` table, which also has a `username` and `password` attribute. I want to check when a login is sent if the username given is in either of the two tables.

Comment: a UNION query might help you. Or just run a query against one table, if you get no results, then run it against the other. Have you tried anything? But really, better to have a single "Users" table. if you need to distinguish between users and teachers, then have a "Role" column within it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `UNION`:

```
'SELECT password FROM student WHERE username = ? 
UNION ALL SELECT password FROM teacher WHERE username = ?',
[username], [username]
```

NB1 : `UNION` requires both queries to return the same number of columns (with the same datatype). Thus it is best to avoid `SELECT *` in this situation. I changed the query to only select the `password` column.

NB2: if the user exists in both tables, the query will return two records. This might, or might not, be what you expect.

Comment: This kind of works, however I need to return either the studentID or teacherID value to the client. But it seems what you are saying is I cannot run: "SELECT password,studentID FROM student WHERE username = ? UNION ALL SELECT password,teacherID FROM teacher WHERE username = ? ". Im not sure how I would process the results either where before it was just results[0].password

Comment: @Stackunderflow: yes, the query that you suggested would work, as long as the datatype of columns `studentID` and `teacherID` is the same (else, you need to do some conversion within the query).

Comment: @Stackunderflow you could run that query, yes, why not? As long as studentID and teacherID are both the same type of column (e.g. int or varchar) it's fine. You might want to give it an alias so it appears just as "ID" consistently in the result.

Comment: @GMB Just tried and it did work, however when processing, i cannot do in my response "id:results[0].(theid)" because it will have a different name depending on which table it was selected from (either student_id or teacher_id)

Comment: @ADyson is an alias the only solution to the problem described in the comment above?

Comment: @Stackunderflow: just: `SELECT password,studentID AS id FROM student WHERE username = ? UNION ALL SELECT password,teacherID FROM teacher WHERE username = ?`. The second column will be called `id`, no matter which table it comes from.

Comment: @Stackunderflow yes, I don't know how else you'd overcome it. An alias is the standard way to rename a column to something else in a SELECT. Have you got a problem with using it??

Comment: Was just curious. Query now working with correct results, thanks. Is there a reason you dont have "SELECT password,studentID AS id FROM student WHERE username = ? UNION ALL SELECT password,teacherID AS id FROM teacher WHERE username = ?" (added "AS id" to second part of statement, after union). not sure how this works @GMB

Comment: @Stackunderflow because then you have a column named both "studentID" and "id". So the same problem as when you had a column named both "studentID" and "teacherID". The point is that the name must be consistent throughout the different sections of the UNION query.